# Cassandra OOM after CMS makes new gens empty

Tags: java, cassandra

My cassandra cluster have 6 nodes, but until now 5 of them went down by map failed caused by OOM.
Before that, CMS throws a WARN log and new-gen becomes totally empty. This is not the typical CMS behavior, but I don't know what's happening.

> WARN  [Service Thread] 2018-10-03 23:47:34,510 GCInspector.java:282 - ConcurrentMarkSweep GC in 4748ms.  CMS Old Gen: 4311229160 -> 1434360152; Par Eden Space: 215565624 -> 0; Par Survivor Space: 6320160 -> 0

I use Cassandra 3.9, and java heap size is 8GB. I don't modify any jvm options.
How should I check next?

Here's the summery of system.log.

```
WARN  [Service Thread] 2018-09-22 16:56:28,089 GCInspector.java:282 - ConcurrentMarkSweep GC in 3926ms.  CMS Old Gen: 1768828144 -> 1173494472; Par Eden Space: 68469544 -> 0; Par Survivor Space: 9587608 -> 0    
ERROR [CompactionExecutor:89253] 2018-09-22 16:56:28,311  CassandraDaemon.java:226 - Exception in thread Thread[CompactionExecutor:89253,1,main]    
org.apache.cassandra.io.FSReadError: java.io.IOException: Map failed
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Map failed
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Map failed
WARN  [GossipTasks:1] 2018-09-22 16:56:38,185 FailureDetector.java:287 - Not marking nodes down due to local pause of 9094437652 > 5000000000
INFO  [CompactionExecutor:89253] 2018-09-22 16:56:38,190 HeapUtils.java:136 - Dumping heap to /cassandra/java_1521034957.hprof ...
Heap dump file created

ERROR [CompactionExecutor:89253] 2018-09-22 16:56:43,305 JVMStabilityInspector.java:141 - JVM state determined to be unstable.  Exiting forcefully due to:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Map failed
```

Comment: how much memory is available on your system?

Answer (score 0):

Its strongly recommended for Cassandra, to use G1GC instead of CMS.

In order to set G1 as the Java garbage collector

- Open jvm.options.
- Comment out the -Xmn800M line.
- Comment out all lines in the ### CMS Settings section.
- Uncomment the relevant G1 settings in the

> G1 Settings section: Use the Hotspot garbage-first collector.
>   -XX:+UseG1GC
>
> Have the JVM do less remembered set work during STW, instead
>   preferring concurrent GC. Reduces p99.9 latency.
>   -XX:G1RSetUpdatingPauseTimePercent=5

[Reference](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsTuneJVM.html#opsTuneJVM__setting-g1-gc) to set G1GC

Answer (score 0):

This looks like your system is throwing OutOfMemory exceptions (including kicking off of the heapdumps). The off heap direct byte buffers by default will allocate up to your heap size - so another 8gb. If your node does not have over 16gb of space you might be hitting limits there. Its also possible your direct byte buffers are overrunning that which can be increased with `-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=12G` (if you have over 16gb). Make sure your kernel settings are configured as well with things like `vm.max_map_count = 1000000` in `/etc/sysctl.conf` and nproc to 32768 memlock unlimited etc. Datastax gives great recommendations at [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.0/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/config/configRecommendedSettings.html) that are relevant to Cassandra as well.